# Converting inbound JSON message to Java Object with Spring

Tags: java, json, spring

I'm trying to create a Java object by deserialising a JSON message in Spring Boot. I have a class as such:

```
public class Status implements Serializable {
    private int uptime;
}
```

Then I have a Rest Controller as such:

```
@RestController
public class StatusReceiver {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/poststatus", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Status storeStatus(@RequestBody Status statusMessage) {

        System.out.println("Uptime: " + statusMessage.getUptime());

        return statusMessage;

    }

}
```

I definitely don't understand a fair bit of what I'm doing here. I want the controller to be creating a Status object when it receives the message and have it store it in the database.

Output of this code is:

```
Uptime: 0
```

The message it's receiving is:

```
{
  "Status": [
    {
      "uptime": 12345.0
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm obviously missing something. How can I have Spring convert the JSON object into the Status java object? Also where is the return from the method meant to be going and doing?

Comment: your code should work. what is the problem exactly?

Comment: Sorry I realised I missed two critical aspects here. Obviously 12345.0 is a Long. I changed the Status member uptime to Long but no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request body JSON is not matching the Status object structure. Either your body should be

```
{uptime: 12345.0}
```

or the Status class should be

```
class Status {
   List<Map<String, Long>> status = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Instead of having a List of Map, you can define a new class and have a list of this new class

```
class StatusInfo{
   long uptime;
}

class Status {
   List<StatusInfo> status = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I guess the first option better reflects what I'm trying to do. I'm now just trying to get it to work with more than one item in the JSON. Turned out to be pretty easy, it's just I need to learn to use JSON better.